Gap in rubber seals on windows - can I bridge with liquid rubber?
I have a UPVC double glazed window which is not closing properly. On inspection there has been considerable water ingress and corrosion (see picture). Ideally I should replace the window entirely, but I am wondering if I can keep it going for a bit longer via a repair. I have scraped off the rust and flushed the metal parts, including the locking mechanism, with WD40. The locking mechanism still functions. I think the reason for the ingress is the gap in the seals running at 45 degrees to the sill (see picture). I was wondering about applying some liquid rubber to this to bridge the gap. Do you think this would work, and if so, what would be the best product? Thanks.


You could just caulk that gap.

Thanks. These are thin rubber strips (difficult to see from the diagram). It needs to be a rubber or rubberlike substance, ideally applicable in layers.

Yes, that is weatherstripping.  I would use a polyreuthane sealant, e.g. OSI Quad Max.

Thanks. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

First, just a clarification—where is the double glazed window you mention?

I opened window to show seals.

So the window in question is just a storm window.

First clean that all. Water shall be there at rain and shall go out by special drainage holes - they need to be clean. Looks like one is visible on picture next to screw head and loaded with dirt.
You can use some grease to protect screws and other metal parts.
DO NOT COVER ANY HOLES OR GAPS - at winter water go  ice and blow up Your window.

Thanks for tip about grease, which would be a good move. I do not see any holes or gaps for water drainage. My main query relates to seals which need to join up, and I was wondering about any liquid rubber product which could be used to fix this without fitting new seals.

P.S. I have just re-read your comment. Are you saying that there should be a gap between the rubber seals (the one running at a 45 degree angle). I had assumed that this is how water had entered in the first place.

There shall be no gap beetwen seals and window but gaps between seals up to 5mm are acceptable. All water shall go out from frame by that hole 2-3 cm wide and 4-5 mm high visible on Your picture under seal next to screw head .

These are tilt and turn windows. If there are drainage holes beneath the problem seals, sealing the corners with polyurethane will tidy up the appearance only. This design expects that water will enter and the drain away naturally. Conversely, air infiltration performance is based on the quality of the seals on the sash and the correct adjustment of the tilt and turn mechanism.
Cover the screws on the frame sill with silicone. Lubricate the tilt and turn mechanism as recommended by the manufacturer.
